# angular $watch oldvalue saved after $destroy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, watch, destroy

I am using Angular 1.4.7.

I have an Angular directive that is sometimes turned off with an ngIf toggle.

Inside the directive I have it watching for changes to an object in a service.

What I am having trouble with is that after the ngIf is toggled to false, then back to true, the directive's scope should effectively reset.

But the "oldVal" in my $watch is being maintained after the $scope is $destroy-ed. Thus when the $scope comes back into existence after the ngIf has been made truthy, the $watch logic always fails to see any change between what it was before being $destroy-ed and after. In other words the new value is the same as the old value, but the old value should be null or something undefined. Of course although it can't tell that the $scope was $destroy-ed, the local data the watch is manipulating and populating is empty.

If I do not perform the check of comparing the old to new value, then the watch triggers additional logic too often.

Why is the 'oldVal' maintained even after the $scope is $destroy-ed, and can I do anything to forcefully clear it out?

```
var module = angular.module('SeFarmFieldsList', ['ui.router']);
module.directive('seFarmFieldsList', 
    ['FarmSvc','MapSvc','FormSvc','UtilSvc',
    function(FarmSvc, MapSvc, FormSvc, UtilSvc) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: false,
            transclude: false,
            scope: {},
            templateUrl: '/views/directives/seFarmFieldsList.html',
            link: function($scope,elem,attributes) {
                console.log('Starting Directive [Farm Fields List]');
                //========== INIT ===================================
                $scope.selFarm = {};
                $scope.fieldListDisplay = [];
                $scope.selFieldId;
                //========= WATCHES ==================================
                $scope.$on('$destroy', function handleDestroyEvent() {
                    console.log('[Farm Fields List] DESTROYED!!!!!!');
                    watch_getSelFarm();
                });

                var watch_getSelFarm = $scope.$watch(
                    function () { 
                        return FarmSvc.getSelFarm();
                        }, 
                    function (newVal, oldVal) {
                        if (!newVal) { return false;}
                        if (newVal === oldVal) { return false; } // <- HERE!
                        $scope.selFarm = newVal;
                        $scope.selFieldId = FarmSvc.getSelFieldId();
                        if (!($scope.selFarm.fields)) { return false; }
                        doStuff();
                    }, true);

[...]
```

Comment: I've never used a `$watch`er in the manner you have where you're watching a service value rather than something on the actual `$scope` but to me that looks a little suspect.  Could it be some underlying mechanism for doing the check against the newVal and oldVal **before** it is triggering your watcher callback caching a value from previous directive instances?

Comment: Also the `true` as the 3rd param in your call to `$watch` might be related to my previous comment.  Look at the docs - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch

You might try setting that to false?

Comment: Hi jusopi, thanks for the input! What is 'suspect' about the $watch on a service variable? I did try disabling the "deep" watch by setting the last value to false, just now, as you suggested, but the result is the same - newval still equals the oldval.

Comment: I just have never used it in that manner.  It's not necessarily wrong, just I raised an eyebrow at it.  What is the return value for `FarmSvc.getSelFarm()`?  I assume an object that's indeed getting reset each time you explicitly clear it out

Comment: When a watcher is called for the first time, angular sets the old value to the same value as the first observed value.

Comment: jusopi - the FarmSvc.getSelFarm() returns the currently active farm object. This does not get reset each time which is the goal - to preserve the selected farm object in the service, and have the various directives that use that service alter the selected farm in different ways. I'm not a guru obviously, but I thought this was a fairly common pattern.

Comment: tasseKATT - well that is very interesting! Is that somewhere in the docs that I missed, then? It certainly explains the behavior.

Comment: tasseKATT - ah, I found it in the docs. I had read it, but I did not really 'get it' but with what you said, I re-read it a few times and now I understand. In the docs for [$rootScope.Scope $watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope): "[...] After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener fn is called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher.[...]" So after the $watch starts, the listener is called once, no matter if the watch expression is true, which will prepare oldVal. If you (tasseKATT) submit this as an answer, I will mark it as such.